# rsort when echoing array_count_values

Tags: php, arrays

This is my code

```
rsort($count_bit);
foreach (array_count_values($count_bit) as $bit => $nums)
{
echo "<tr><td width='90%'>Version: " . $bit .  "</td><td>" . $nums . "</td></tr>";
}
```

That echoes out a random order, i think its because it sorts the $count_bit which later is run through array_count_values so its actually this i need to sort: array_count_values($count_bit) and not $count_bit, i tried

```
foreach (rsort(array_count_values($count_bit)) as $bit => $nums)
```

but that didnt work, i thought about also doing

```
$count_bit1 = new array($count_bit);
rsort($count_bit1);
```

but then when i echoed it out $bit just showed as 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8 and lost its unique values. Any ideas

Any example of what im dealing with is this:

```
 Version: 665   14
 Version: 645   1
 Version: 660   5
 Version: 651   1
 Version: 662   1
 Version: 649   1
```

And i want it display 14,5,1,1,1,1 not random like it is

$bit echoes out the version number and $nums echoes out how many of that version number it found in the original loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this function to sort your array :

It takes 3 arguments :

1) Array which you want to sort.
2) Index by which you want to sort that array.
3) Sort order (SORT_ASC or SORT_DESC)

You can call this like this :

```
array_sort($array, 'array_index', SORT_DESC);
```

Don't assign the return result into any variable or array. It will automatically sort that array and will assign the new sorted array into that same array variable.

```
function array_sort($array, $sort_by, $order=SORT_ASC)
    {
        $new_array = array();
        $sortable_array = array();

        if (count($array) > 0) {
            foreach ($array as $k => $v) {
                if (is_array($v)) {
                    foreach ($v as $k2 => $v2) {
                        if ($k2 == $on) {
                            $sortable_array[$k] = strtolower($v2);
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    $sortable_array[$k] = strtolower($v);
                }
            }

            switch ($order) {
                case SORT_ASC:
                    asort($sortable_array);
                break;
                case SORT_DESC:
                    arsort($sortable_array);
                break;
            }

            foreach ($sortable_array as $k => $v) {
                $new_array[$k] = $array[$k];
            }
        }

        return $new_array;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The ordering of your logic is what is off.

In your first example, your sorting the array then using `array_count_value` which creates a new array (unsorted).

In your second, you using the return value of `rsort` in your `foreach` loop. [`rsort`](http://php.net/rsort) returns a boolean value.

You need to use [`arsort`](http://php.net/arsort) because it maintains the indexes of the array, whereas `rsort` rekeys your array numerically when it does the sorting. This is why your "Version" was becoming incremented numbers.

**PHP**

```
$new_array = array_count_values($count_bit);
arsort($new_array);
foreach($new_array as $bit => $nums)
{
    // Output your html with your values here
    echo sprintf("Version: %s > Count: %s\n", $bit, $nums);
}
```

**Output (my own array example)**

```
Version: 665 > Count: 11
Version: 660 > Count: 2
Version: 662 > Count: 1
Version: 645 > Count: 1
Version: 642 > Count: 1
```